# How to say "I've been busy with something"

Tags: questions

I am trying to figure the correct way to answer the question:

> 授業をサボった時にどんな言い訳をよくしますか。

I want to say:
"Usually I say i've been busy with my internship to the extend that I couldn't come to class"

which I wrote initially as:

> 授業に来られないほど忙しにインタンシップをしましたことをよく言います

but idk if 忙しに is the best form of saying an internship that had me busy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

授業に出る is more natural. You must change an adjective 忙しい to that of continuous form 忙しく. And していましたと is natural.

So I rephrase your translation as 授業に出られないほど忙しくインターンシップをしていましたとよく言います.

"I've been busy with something” is translated as で忙しい, so you can rephrase your example as 授業に出られないほどインターンシップで忙しかったとよく言います.

Moreover, インターンシップで忙しくて授業に出られませんでした is more common.

Comment: 「インター**ン**シップ」じゃない？

Answer (score 0):

用事{ようじ}がある is a pretty common way of being vague about what you're doing while giving the impression that it's something that keeps you busy.

To be even more vague, you can say 「用事があって」and end it there.

Comment: yeah, or if Bobby specifically wants to use the internship as the excuse, it could be used in: 「授業に出られなかった理由は インターシップについて用事があったから。」or something similar.

Comment: ^ インターシップじゃなくてインターンシップじゃないの... 「インターンシップ**について**用事があったから。」ってたぶん言わないなー